# What's the name of the device that reverses on-off state based on second power input on-off?

Tags: power, switches, dc

Specifically what I'd like to achieve is find an electronic switch that connects to a car's ignition system and that has a second circuit in it that is kept active (on) when the ignition is off, and set to inactive (off) when the ignition is on. Kinda like an automatic emergency light system that turns on when power is lost, and turns off when the power is back. Also, everything is DC (12v from car battery to switch the state of the second circuit, which is 5v only).

Comment: It's called a "relay". You will use the normally closed contact which will open when the coil is energised.

Comment: @Transistor that "relay" will use the current of the battery to go into the other circuit, essentially powering the lights AKA "relaying" the power to it? Can you explain the logic of this "relay", how will it "trigger" / close the other circuit? Because it seems to me there has to be another component between the one from the batter to the second circuit, or else there'd be power flowing from the car battery into the power source of the lights (they have their own).

Comment: A relay is essentially an electrically-operated switch.  The relay coil, an electromagnet that moves the switch contacts when powered, is electrically insulated from the switch contacts.

Answer (score 0):

**relay** noun /ˈriːleɪ/

> an electrical device, typically incorporating an electromagnet, which is activated by a current or signal in one circuit to open or close another circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzLJ8a.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Suggested circuit. Don't skip the fuse.*

How it works:

- When the ignition is off the relay is off.
- When the relay is off power is fed out through the normally closed (NC) contact to your loads.
- When the ignition is switched on RLY1 is energised and the NC contact opens disconnecting the load.

Comment: "Relay" is the name of the component in a device; the post was asking asking for the name of what such a device would be called.

Comment: The device you need is a relay. Nothing else (other than the fuse). See the circuit schematic. If it makes it seem like more of a device, then a relay contains a coil, an armature, a spring and a set of contacts.